# How to set auto fill to grid column width

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, grid

I have a grid with only one row with the height of GridLength.Star. 
In the first column I have an svg that fills the cell. 
In the second column I have a label.

The svg is a square and should take the place to fill it in vertical and horizontal direction but not more. 
The label should take the rest of the width.

I tried to set

```
column1.Width = GridLength.Auto;
column2.Width = GridLength.Star;
```

but it will always be devided in the middle.

So I got:

svg..........|label........

instead of (what I want):

svg|label..................

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

```
Label label = new Label();

SvgCachedImage svgImage = new SvgCachedImage();
svgImage.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand;
svgImage.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand;

Grid grid = new Grid();
grid.Children.Add( svgImage );
grid.Children.Add( label );

RowDefinition row = new RowDefinition();
ColumnDefinition column1 = new ColumnDefinition();
ColumnDefinition column2 = new ColumnDefinition();

row.Height = GridLength.Star;
grid.RowDefinitions = new RowDefinitionCollection { row1 };
column1.Width = GridLength.Auto;
column2.Width = GridLength.Star;
grid.ColumnDefinitions = new ColumnDefinitionCollection { column1, column2 };
```

**UPDATE 2**

Sorry it is no Fill but a CenterAndExpand

Comment: How big is your SVG? Does it take up the full half?

Comment: The size of the svg does not matter because it always fills the first cell and so it modifys its size.

Comment: Can you show your current setup (XAML/C#) for the Grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer. I simply need to set the height of the svg to its widthRequest:

```
 svgImage.WidthRequest = svgImage.Height;
 column1.Width = GridLength.Auto;
 column2.Width = GridLength.Star;
 grid.Children.Add( svgImage, 0, 0 );
 grid.Children.Add( label, 1, 0 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, its very simple actually the reason behind it is the `GridLength.Auto` you have there all you need to do is change the Grid column definitions into something like this:

**XAML**

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/> // svg
  <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/> // label
</Grid.CoulmnDefinitions>
```

**C#**

```
Grid grid= new Grid
{
    ColumnDefinitions = 
            {
               new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) }, 
               new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(4, GridUnitType.Star) },
            }
}

grid.Children.Add(svgImage, 0, 0);
grid.Children.Add(label, 0, 1);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I already tried that, but it does not solve my problem, because when the width of my first column becomes to small my svg is getting smaller.

Comment: What percentage of your width do you want the svg to cover

Comment: I dont want to set a percentage. I want to fit exactly. Otherwise it would be ok to take the height of the cell. But this height is set to "*" which is not correct for the width.

Comment: Okay then in that case you are doing it the other way around you should do this instead `column2.Width = GridLength.Auto;
column1.Width = GridLength.Star;`

Comment: Doesn't Auto take the space its needed and star the possoble space? This unfortunately does not solve my problem. It's getting even worse.

Comment: `Auto` automatically sizes to fit content in the row or column whereas `*` sizes columns and rows as a proportion of the remaining space. And if that doesn't work nothing else will. You will be wasting your time trying to find a solution as Forms is not like android where you can just width to wrap_content and it does all for you. You will have to give it proportional values at one point.

Answer (score 0):

Move:

```
grid.Children.Add( svgImage );
grid.Children.Add( label );
```

to after you've set up your row/column definitions, and then change to:

```
grid.Children.Add(svgImage, 0, 0);
grid.Children.Add(label, 0, 1);
```

You basically have to tell the grid which row/column to put your elements. By adding them to the grid before initialising the column definitions, the `ColumnDefinition`s have defaulted to `GridLength.Star`.

---

I've tidied up your code. Note that I have changed the `Height` assignments.

```cs
Label label = new Label()
{
   Text = "Some text" // Just some placeholder text
};

SvgCachedImage svgImage = new SvgCachedImage()
{
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
};

Grid grid = new Grid();

// NOTE: use GridLength class to set the Height/Width of rows/columns
RowDefinition row = new RowDefinition()
{
    Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)
}
ColumnDefinition column1 = new ColumnDefinition()
{
    Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto)
}
ColumnDefinition column2 = new ColumnDefinition()
{
    Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)
}

// Use existing instances of the definitions
grid.RowDefinitions.Add(row1);
grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column1);
grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column2);

grid.Children.Add(svgImage, 0, 0);
grid.Children.Add(label, 1, 0);
```

As I was typing this out I noticed that you had simply set the `Width` property to `GridLength.Star/Auto`. According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid#rows-and-columns), you should be using the `GridLength` **class**, not the Enum.

Comment: thanks for your reply but that event does not change a thing, because the columndefinition is still the same.

Comment: I've tidied up your code and noticed you're using `GridLength` as an enum. This should be a **class**. See my modified answer.

Comment: this does exactly the same (check the xamarin code comment)

Comment: You're right (I personally like to be explicit). I've just changed the ordering of the children, as it should be `Add(View, Column, Row)`.